# img.responsive class in wordpress not working

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, image-resizing

Help me make images automatically resize as the browser size is reduced.

I have added a wordpress blog to my hand coded site. It's in the directory /blog 
http://photographyattic.com/blog/
I include wordpress snippet code to add posts on my /index.php page. 
The site is made using Bootstrap 3. The top of the page where the wordpress post is is using bootstrap grid 
container 
row
col-md-2 (left panels), col-md-7 (wordpress content) and col-md-3 (right panels)

I have tried several forum suggested fixes to make the image scale down as the browser window is resized. But as you see it remains the 770pixel width and goes under col-md-3  when the browser window is reduced. 
I would have thought adding the img-responsive class to the wordpress media form would have resolved the issue, but it doesn't. The only way I have been able to get the image to resize is adding position absolute to a new img class, and then the image overlays the text but does resize as I'd like.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post some of your code personally i always set the img width to 100% and height to auto to have it scale correctly and then using the div it is in that would control the width.

Comment: Your image dimensions (and other elements) are stated as inline styles in the HTML. You should probably remove those. In fact the whole page is acting odd on re-size.

Comment: Thanks Travis..I have img width to 100% and height to auto but it's not been resizing and it looks like Paulie has nailed it. I have just removed width and height from the wordpress edit page and the image resizes as I want. Does this mean every time I upload an image I have to edit the Wordpress code to remove the sizes added automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i can see the images are responsive according to screen size.the costume width and height attributes may cause the problem.if you want to avoid the insert image functionality from adding  width and height attributes automatically ,add the following code to your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'remove_width_attribute', 10 );
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'remove_width_attribute', 10 );

function remove_width_attribute( $html ) {
   $html = preg_replace( '/(width|height)="\d*"\s/', "", $html );
   return $html;
}
```

**Update:**
In the wp-settings.php file on line 135 you'll see these two lines:

```
require (ABSPATH . WPINC . '/functions.php');
require (ABSPATH . WPINC . '/plugin.php');
```

Just reverse the order they're listed in because the add_filter() function is NOT in the functions.php file; it's in the plugin.php file so... they should now look like this:

```
require (ABSPATH . WPINC . '/plugin.php');
require (ABSPATH . WPINC . '/functions.php');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've seen a few options to add functions but when I try them they always give "Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_filter()" What extra code am I missing please?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_filter() in /xxx/xxx/xxx/blog/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4195

Comment: I updated my answer ..please try that and you're GOOD TO GO!!

Comment: brilliant that worked. Can I ask why switching the order of functions.php and plugin.php in the wp-settings.php file makes any difference? And will that affect anything else that requires functions.php to be first

Comment: the ans for this questions also lies in my above answer :)  `add_filter()`function is NOT in the functions.php file; it's in the plugin.php file.in simple words  in first case function.php is executing the function with out define it ...when in second case first the `add_filter()` will define in plugin.php and then function.php is executing it ...Make sense ? :)

Comment: ok thank you - I understand what you say I just dont understand the process. and why Wordpress doesnt supply the page with the lines in the correct order if plugin defines before the function executes

Comment: the functions.php instillation version won't have any code with `add_filter()` function.may be the that is the reason why they won't worry about the order. when we are inserting our new custom code into our function.php we should take care of it (i believe) :) also please vote my answer so that other peoples with similar issue will know that this is the solution what they are looking for :)

Comment: I already liked it, but I cant vote as I dont have enough points yet. I will do when I reach base :-) Thanks